# Cucumber reports plugin in Bamboo

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, cucumber, bamboo

I want to configure cucumber report tool in Bamboo. It has procedure to do it in Jenkins.

https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting

I know there are bunch of plugins available in marketplace. But I don't need them. Did anyone succeeded in configuring the damian's cucumber report plugin in Bamboo.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I configured masterthought cucumber reports in Bamboo

1. Add the following plugin code in pom file

   ```
           <plugin>
           <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
           <version>3.4.0</version>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>execution</id>
                   <phase>test</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>generate</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-maven-reports</outputDirectory>
                       <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
             </executions>
           </plugin>
   ```
2. Now go to bamboo and select **configure** plan and then click on the job in the **Stages** tab
3. Now you are on the **Tasks**. Click on **Artifacts** tabs
4. Click on Create Definition button and input the below details.

   - Name: CukeReports
   - Location: target/cucumber-maven-reports
   - Copy pattern: `**/*.*` (This will copy all the folders and subfolders and files recursively)

Now run your build and you can able to access these reports in the **Artifacts** tab of your build summary. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As this plugin generates HTML report you can create artifact in Bamboo to include that report as build artifact. Then you will see it in artifact list and view it via web browser. It will be not inlined into Bamboo UI, but you can view test results anyway

Comment: I will upvote for the idea. I will answer complete solution so that it helps others :-)